# Getting the SOAP version in a JAX-WS Provider

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

Is there a way to get the SOAP version (1.1 / 1.2) of a request, in a JAX-WS Provider? (@ServiceMode(Mode.PAYLOAD))

Let's say my service supports both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2. When I assemble a SOAP Fault in my Provider, I have to know the SOAP version (because the SOAP Fault's structure is dependent on the SOAP version). However I have found no way to get this information.

Comment: If you are running it as an EndPoint you could have an endpoint for each SOAP version using BindingType i.e. @BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)

Comment: I think you can extract it from soap header and put it into ur fault string.

Comment: I could get it from the SOAP Envelope's namespace, if I use @ServiceMode(Mode.MESSAGE). But, as I wrote, I want to use @ServiceMode(Mode.PAYLOAD). I think the JAX-WS runtime has the version information (it had to parse the SOAP message).